# Which Android APIs are enough to target maximum number of devices?

Tags: android

I am thinking to make an application but at the time I don't have API 21 and API 22 installed on my SDK due to some network problems and I'm unable to download any thing at the moment. I was wondering if I can make an app effective enough to target many devices without using API 21 and API 22.

Comment: API version 21 and 22 is around 12.2% based on google app store app calculation by google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bilal, judging from your comments to others, I'm getting the impression that you don't fully understand how the API levels work in Android. Let me try and explain.

The minimum API level is pretty self-explanatory, as it refers to the minimum Android OS version that can run your app. You want to set this as low as possible to target the most devices. To determine which level you set depends entirely on your application. For example, if your app requires access to the Calendar APIs, your minimum API level would be 7, because that is when those APIs were introduced.

You almost *always* want to set your maximum API level to the highest possible. Google encourages this, because it allows you to take advantage of all of the new APIs that have been released. But what about the devices that are outdated? You can still enable backwards compatibility with those devices using the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Finally, it is not necessary to download each and every API level in the SDK manager. You only need to download the most recent.